# Making smaller a string, c#

Tags: c#

I need a library/tool/function that compresses a 50-60 char long string to smaller.

Do you know any?

Comment: Encryption generally doesn't make data smaller. Do you mean compression?

Comment: And it is impossible to do this for all strings because of the pigeonhole principle (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Comment: can you tell us what these strings will look like? what characters they will contain? a few samples would be good

Comment: @Eilon excepted if you share the pigeonholes (shared dictionary in a dictionary based compression) :-) see my answer (smaz)

Comment: Explain more about the problem to get better answers.

Comment: It's a URL with some Query Strings. The max length is about 100 chars but the minimum, I guess, 50-60.

Answer (score 5):

Effective compression on that scale will be difficult. You might consider [Huffman coding](http://www.enusbaum.com/blog/2009/05/22/example-huffman-compression-routine-in-c/). This might give you smaller compression than gzip (since it will result in binary codes instead of a base-85 sequence).

Comment: OK then, I need some test classes :)

Comment: @Kaan, I'm happy to spend a few minutes putting together an example, but, as others have said, they won't be that useful unless you can provide some examples of the strings you're working with.

Comment: here is the example: http://localhost:52294/Default.html?LA=40,9305222197136&LO=29,8102416992188&N=t%FCrkiye%20denemE&D=kaan&M=r&Z=4, thank you David :)

Comment: @Kaan localhost urls aren't accessible from anywhere but your machine. Is there a certain part of that url that you need to compress, or the whole thing?

Comment: @David? Won't you give me examples? :))

Answer (score 1):

The framework includes the [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) and [`DeflateStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.deflatestream.aspx) classes. But that might not really be what you are after - what input strings have to be compressed? ASCII only? Letters only? Alphanumerical string? Full Unicode? And what are allowed output strings?

From an algorithmic stand point and without any further knowledge of the space of possible inputs I suggest to use [arithmetic coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding). This might shrink the compressed size by a few additional bits compared to [Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) because it is not restricted to an integral number of bits per symbol - something that can turn out important when dealing with such small inputs.

Comment: GZip requires minimum 18 bytes overhead, which is going to kill its effectiveness on this scale.

Answer (score 1):

Are you perhaps thinking of a cryptographic hash? For example, SHA-1 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) can be used on an input string to produce a 20-byte digest. Of course, the digest will always be 20 bytes - even if the input string is shorter than 20 bytes.

Comment: A hash is not compression nor encryption

Comment: Considering the ambiguity of the original question, this may well be the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your string only contains lowercase characters between a-z and 0-9 you could encode it in 7bits.

This will compress a 60 char string to 53 bytes. If you don't need digits you could use 6bits instead, bringing it down to 45 bytes.

So choosing the right compression method depends on what data your string contains.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply gzip it

http://www.example-code.com/csharp/gzip_compressString.asp

Comment: Considering that GZip requires a minumum 10-byte header and an 8-byte footer, this solution isn't appropriate for a 50-60 char string.

Comment: I agree with David... I tested with 100 chars then the result came up with 170 chars..

Answer (score 0):

I would use some basic like [RLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) or shared dictionary based compression followed by a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation) that keeps the size constant.

Maybe [smaz](http://github.com/antirez/smaz) is also interesting for you.

Examples of basic compression algorithms:

- RLE
- (Modified or not) Huffman coding
- Burrows-Wheeler transformation

Examples of block ciphers ("bit twiddlers"):

- AES
- Blowfish
- DES
- Triple DES
- Serpent
- Twofish

You will be able to find out what fullfills your needs using wikipedia (links above).

Comment: Not a bad suggestion if the input data is expected to have many internal runs of identical data. Typical text data does not fit that requirement.